# Re-declaring arrow function

Tags: javascript, function, var, arrow-functions, let

tried to re-declare an arrow function-- (Check code)

[image]

Why is it giving error when `var` can be redeclared.

I made an arrow function using `var` then tried re-declaring it using `let` as `var` can be redeclared. But why is it giving error?

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrow functions and everything to do with `const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a variable with `var`, you can redeclare a variable with `var` as many times as you like, but it will error if you redeclare with `let` or `const`. With `let` and `const`, you can only declare a variable one.

What you probably meant to do is reassign the variable, which you can do as many times as you want with `var` or `let`, just don't add `var` or `let` again.

#### Redeclaring

```js
// valid, but not advised
var cube = (num) => num * num * num;
var cube = (num) => num * num * num;
```

```js
// invalid
var cube = (num) => num * num * num;
let cube = (num) => num * num * num;
```

```js
// invalid
var cube = (num) => num * num * num;
const cube = (num) => num * num * num;
```

#### Reassigning

```js
// valid
var cube = (num) => num * num * num;
cube = (num) => num * num * num;
```

```js
// valid
let cube = (num) => num * num * num;
cube = (num) => num * num * num;
```

```js
// invalid - can't change a const
const cube = (num) => num * num * num;
cube = (num) => num * num * num;
```

Comment: I got that we cannot change var to let in same scope but somehow this is possible if let and var are in different scopes. Like this one :                                                                              var a = 1;
var b = 2;

if (a === 1) {
  var a = 11; // the scope is global
  let b = 22; // the scope is inside the if-block

  console.log(a); // 11
  console.log(b); // 22
}                                                                                                                                             How is this possible?

Comment: @leo_00 `var` variables in JavaScript are function-scoped, not block-scoped.